How to use asynchronous method with Textractor?
I am trying to use the Textractor package but with a multipage document. I am able to get synchronous method to work using for loop like so:
import os
from textractor import Textractor
from textractor.data.constants import TextractFeatures
import pypdfium2 as pdfium

pdf = pdfium.PdfDocument("myFile.pdf")
extractor = Textractor(region_name="us-east-1")


def convert_to_image(pdf, n):

   page=pdf[n]

   bitmap = page.render(
   scale = 1,
   rotation = 0, 
   extra_flags = 0,
   grayscale = False,
   fill_color = (255, 255, 255, 255),
   color_scheme = None,
   optimize_mode = None,
   draw_annots = True,
   may_draw_forms = True,
   no_smoothtext = False,
   no_smoothimage = False,
   no_smoothpath = False,
   force_halftone = False,
   rev_byteorder = False,
   prefer_bgrx = False,
   force_bitmap_format = None
   #extra_flags = 0,
   #allocator = None,
   #memory = 
   )
   image = bitmap.to_pil()

   return image

doc_words = []
doc_lines = []
for i in range(0, len(pdf)):
    print('page', i)
    pdf_page = convert_to_image(pdf, i)
    document = extractor.analyze_document(
        file_source=pdf_page,
        features=[TextractFeatures.FORMS, TextractFeatures.TABLES, TextractFeatures.SIGNATURES ])
    doc_words.append(document.words)
    doc_lines.append(document.lines)

However, I am not able to use the async method with multipage PDFs unless I do a similar example as above where I am converting each single page into an image. Is there a way to just read in the multi-page PDF and have all the text from the pages outputted without doing a for loop and converting each page in the document to an image?
I am trying:
document = extractor.start_document_analysis(
              file_source = "myFile.pdf",
              s3_upload_path="s3uploadpath",
              features=[TextractFeatures.FORMS, TextractFeatures.TABLES, TextractFeatures.SIGNATURES])

but getting the error:
PDFInfoNotInstalledError: Unable to get page count. Is poppler installed and in PATH?


This is because by default Textractor tries to rasterize the PDF in order to allow visualization lateer.
You have two ways to solve it, either you install the pdf version:
pip install amazon-textract-textractor[pdf]
Or you call the method with save_image=False
document = extractor.start_document_analysis(
              file_source = "myFile.pdf",
              s3_upload_path="s3uploadpath",
              features=[TextractFeatures.FORMS, TextractFeatures.TABLES, TextractFeatures.SIGNATURES],
              save_image=False
)

However there is an open issue that this might not work as expected: https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-textract-textractor/issues/366
